# How to Use Variables in Access SQL Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I'm working on a project which requires I use a large number of columns in my Access SQL queries. A typical query contains several fields such as the one below:

```
SELECT ([Score1]+[Score2]+[Score3])*.5 AS [Scores], [Subject] FROM [ScoresTable]
WHERE ([Score1]+[Score2]+[Score3])*.5 > 500
```

Is there any way to assign the value of `([Score1]+[Score2]+[Score3])*.5` to a variable so I could in effect write something like:

```
SELECT ([Score1]+[Score2]+[Score3])*.5 AS [Scores] *= VAR*, [Subject] 
FROM [ScoresTable] WHERE *VAR* > 500
```

If it is possible, could you please show me how to achieve such results?

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: You may find it convenient to use two queries, one which has the calculations and a second query where you select the records with the calculations that are of interest (WHERE).

Comment: I do not know Access, but can't you just create a VIEW that gets columns Scores and Subject from ScoresTable and then query that VIEW instead of the ScoresTable?

Comment: @Peter van der Heijden, in Access, Views are usually called queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sq.Scores, sq.Subject
FROM (
    SELECT (Score1+Score2+Score3)*.5 AS Scores, Subject
    FROM ScoresTable
    ) AS sq
WHERE sq.Scores > 500;
```

If Score1, Score2, or Score3 can be Null, you may want to use the Nz function to substitute zero for Null.